# Can't write report output to folder with read+write access: permission denied

Tags: jasperserver

I have a user with the `ROLE_USER` role (assigned via LDAP group) and I have a folder structure like this:

```
/root
    /Completed Reports
```

Users with the `ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR` can write to `Completed Reports` (specifically, requesting that a report be scheduled/run-in-background with output to a file in that folder), but users with `ROLE_USER` cannot.

I have set the permissions like this:

```
/root
   ROLE_ADMIMISTRATOR (Administer)
   ROLE_ANONYMOUS     (No Access*)   <-- * means "inherited"
   ROLE_USER          (Read Only)

/Completed Reports
   ROLE_ADMIMISTRATOR (Administer)
   ROLE_ANONYMOUS     (No Access*)
   ROLE_USER          (Read + Write)
```

I also took a specific user and added permissions for that user specifically:

```
/Completed Reports
   ttest              (Read + Write)
```

Yet, when I attempt to run a report in the background and write a PDF file to `/root/Completed Reports`, I get an error attempting to save the job, saying:

```
You do not have permission to save the job output to the /Completed_Reports folder. Select another location to save the job.
```

I checked, and the user `ttest` can create new folders within `/Completed Reports`. Why can't I save a completed report to this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this was confusion on my part about what "write" means. Evidently, "write" really means "modify" or something like that. In order to be able to save the output of a report-execution, you need to have the "delete" privilege.

[Surprise!](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-administrator-guide/v630/repository-permissions) (look for "output of a scheduled report")